# Sympy function evaluated at symbol

Tags: python, function, sympy, derivative, evaluate

I have a problem with the symbolic Python package Sympy.
Perhaps I am missing some obvious tools in Sympy but I have read through the documentation and not come across a solution.

My question is can the derivative of `g(f(y)) = g(f(x))|_(x=y)` with respect to `x` be obtained in the form `Derivative(f(x), x)(y)` in Sympy? And if so how?

Here is a simple example: I have a symbolic function of one variable e.g. `f(x)`.
I have another expression `g`, which calls this function with input arguments
represented by other symbols, i.e. `g(f(y))` where `y = Symbol('y')`.
I implement this with the following:

```
x = Symbol('x')
f = Function('f')(x)
y = Symbol('y')
g = Function('g')(f).subs('x','y')
```

My goal is then to evaluate the derivative of g wrt x at x=y, something like 
`Derivative(f(x), x)(y) * Derivative(g(f), f)(f(y))`

This can be roughly achieved with
`diff(g, y) = Derivative(f(y), y)*Derivative(g(f(y)), f(y))`.
The problem here is that the term `Derivative(f(y), y)` in this case is the derivative evaluated at y.
I have expressions for the derivatives of functions wrt all input variables, i.e. `Derivative(f(x), x)` in this case, and not wrt y since it is not a variable of f. Hence, I would like the derivative expressed in the form `Derivative(f(x), x)(y)` to avoid repeating the same expression for all the possible variables used.
(For completeness, the term `diff(g, x)=0` since any instances of x have been replaced by y.)

To enforce the notion that g is a function of x evaluated at y, replacing the method `subs` of the fourth line above with the `evalf` method could be the right path. But it seems that expression can only be evaluated at particular values and not other symbolic variables.

Any help and advice is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the differentiation in `Subs` seems to work; it is a delayed substitution.

```
>>> from sympy import Subs, sin, cos
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> f, g = symbols('f g', cls=Function)
>>> Subs(g(f(x)).diff(x),x,y).subs(g,sin).subs(f,cos).doit(
... ) == Subs(sin(cos(x)).diff(x),x,y).doit()
True
```